# PowerShell Remoting when proxy server is used for LAN

Tags: powershell, ssl, https, proxy, remote-server

A Proxy server is used for the LAN connectivity in my machine and when i try to create a remote powershell session using the command **Enter-PSSession** in my machine, powershell console throws the following exception,

[First Try: Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server.com -Credential domain\user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N28tr.jpg)

Now, I tried along with -UseSSL option. Below is the exception i received this time,

[Second Try:  Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server.com -Credential domain\user -useSSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEY0j.jpg)

Can anyone please let me know how to create remote powershell session when in proxy LAN connection ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set proxy settings on connections for PS Remoting, use the `New-PSSessionOptions` commandlet and save the results as an object.  `$sessionOptions = New-PSSessionOptions [...]` (you may need to research the options to specify there)

Then, use this object as a parameter on the -SessionOptions switch

Comment: Thanks for the idea. :)